# mb_language()とmb_send_mail()の設定方法

Tags: php, centos

いつもお世話になります。
◆やりたいこと 
centos7上でmailサーバ(postfix)を立て、PHPのソースからメールを送信したいです。

◆現在ハマっているところ 
// test_mail.php

```
コードをここに入力
<?php
 $mail = "test@exmaple.com";
 $subject = "テストメールです";
 $body = "本文です";
 mb_language("Japanese");
 $ret=mb_send_mail($mail,$subject,$body);
 var_dump($ret);
```

というコードを実行しました。

```
コードをここに入力
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_language() in 
/root/mail_test.php on line 5
```

というエラーがでました。
ここの部分をコメントアウトしてさらに実行すると、

```
コードをここに入力
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_send_mail() in 
/root/mail_test.php on line 6
```

エラーがでます。表題のとおりmb_language()とmb_send_mail()の設定ができません。

◆行ったこと
①PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_language() in /root/mail_test.php on line 5
に対しては、yum -y install php_mbstringをインストールしてみました。

②PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_send_mail() in /root/mail_test.php on line 6
は、php.iniの設定でコメントアウトされているかと思いを見てみましたが、コメントアウトされていませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちらの[スレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/17784/13972)はチェックされましたでしょうか。承認された回答こそありませんが、コメント中に示されたチェック項目は十分役立ちそうに思いますが。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/73435

Comment: 連絡が遅くなり、すいません。centosのphp環境を再構築したら、うまく動作しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

mb_language, mb_sendはphp-mbstringがinstallされてから利用できる関数です。

centosの場合なら、下記のでinstallできます。

```
# yum install php-mbstring
```

php.iniファイルにmbstringの設定がされているかもチェックした方が良いです。

Comment: 連絡が遅くなり、すいません。centosのphp環境を再構築したら、うまく動作しました。ありがとうございます。 –